# Express.js: Headers already sent on REST API

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, http-headers

I've create a REST API with Node.js and Express.js.
On an URL, I got an error message when I call this URL more the once:

> send json error: [Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.]

So, I added a try catch to catch the error. But strangely, this work fine. The error is catched and my response is sent:

```
try {
  res.status(200).json(user);
} catch (e) {
  console.log('send json error:',e);
}

res.on('finish', function() {
  console.log('All is ok, response sent with user datas');
});
```

I think it's not very clean solution. So I would like to know why this error is throw and how I can write a clean solution for this problem ?

Comment: Can you share your complete code where you are getting this issue?

Comment: Can you show your original code?  The likely answer is that you're calling res.json() in one handler after your error handler is already sending something down the response stream

Comment: @Paul:
Here the very long code: https://jsfiddle.net/120sav99/

Comment: You should write your code  in modular form it'll create issue during debugging.Try to break it in small functions

Comment: Your code seems fine. Try adding the exact code that caused this exception and add the exception logs too (with line number). It might help with debugging.

Answer (score 1):

So from your JSFiddle, I have to say that there's a *lot* you could do to modularize/cleanup your code.  It's very difficult right now to figure out what's happening where.  While using the fat arrow notation for closures is handy, it's really hard to debug with when you have a lot of them in sequence or in parallel as they are completely anonymous.

You also don't indicate anywhere what *other* middleware is firing along that route, which could *also* be a source of multiple response attempts.

All that said, the *first* thing to do is very simple:  Add a return statement before each call to `res.send()` or `res.end()`.  Anytime you call one of those, you want your current function to stop doing anything, so be explicit about that, and a lot of this class of problems goes away.

Second, add named functions for every promise handler or callback in your code.  This will at least give you cleaner stack traces and make your code more intuitive to other maintainers.

Third, consider grouping those functions into other files in a logical fashion that you can require by name.  This will further illuminate your stack trace (by giving you file names and line numbers to look at).

Finally, install and use node-inspector or a similar debugging tool religiously, set breakpoints and step through your code.

// Edit after the OPs comment below

I disagree that the code organization is not the main issue with the post.  It is absolutely leading to the main issue.  Your comment (which really should have been in the original question) indicates that the closure in question is firing twice.   That closure is the event handler for a *global* object (bad idea) that is firing an event when user data is loaded, but you're pushing the scope of the current handler down into it (the response object), which is a common problem you run into when you organize code the way you have (scope bleed).

Through better modularization / structure, those kinds of problems become more obvious more quickly.  What you're suggesting is something of a hack to solve the problem; the real solution is to better understand when things happen in your application and why.

In this case, look to why that user data loaded event is firing more than once.  I'm guessing it should not be (at least not in the scope of the same request), but if it should be and that's OK, then use the correct promise chain behavior to handle it only once (whether that's the first time or the last time is up to your needs), and only call the `res.json()` when  you're really ready to (and again, only once).

Comment: All good points. I would personally suggest that OP learns how to properly work with promises, and in particular promise chaining, because the current code is basically callback-hell-using-promises.

Comment: Thank's for your reply.
I know my code need a massive refactoring, but it's not the main problem in this subject :)

In the JSFiddle, the response who return an error is at the line 46.
The first time where I use this function, all is ok, not any error. But the second time, the try/catch catch the error "headers already sent", but the response is still sent.

I don't understand why and how it's possible.

I find this: [headersSent](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.headersSent).
Perhaps a solution with this ?

Comment: @robertklep yep, which is why I tend to debate folks who answer "how do I do this?" with "use Promises, they're way better than callbacks".  The truth is, you can write bad code using anything, and you can write good code using (just about) anything.

Comment: @Paul: In any cases, Promises or Callbacks are not the question here. Please keep in mind the original question ;)

Comment: @Nowis I never said anything about promises vs. callbacks in my answer.  My comment was in response to robertklep's (correct) point that you can make promise hell just like you can make callback hell.  I have no issue with promises; just with the argument that they're a silver bullet for bad code.